# How to graph the following square root function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would you graph $f(x) = \sqrt{a^2 +x^2}$ ? What does the "a" mean in the equation?

Comment: $a$ is some constant. You have to try out a few values and see how $a$ affects the graph.

Comment: Probably just a free parameter (a constant). What you could do is to write the function as $f(x) = a\sqrt{1 + (x/a)^2}$ and plot $f(x)/a$ in terms of $x/a$ - then the function is just $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ and the information about $a$ is in the definition of the axis you use.

Answer (score 1):

The $a$ represents half the length of your major and minor axis of a hyperbola

Showing,

$$y = \sqrt{x^2 + a^2}$$
$$y^2 - x^2 = a^2$$
$$\frac{y^2}{a^2} - \frac{x^2}{a^2} = 1$$

Comment: So this is a standard hyperbola?

Comment: @Arithmetician it's the top half of one, yes.

Comment: doesn't a hyperbola have a b^2 under the x^2? The a and the b in the equation would help to draw the asymptotes of the hyperbola

Comment: in this case $a=b$